# awesome-wm: binding programs to workspaces

Tags: awesome-wm

Could you please suggest some simple method of binding certain programs/windows to their own workspaces? E. g. firefox is always to be started on workspace 1, chromium - workspace 2, terminal - workspace 3 etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Related : http://superuser.com/q/513707/162290

Answer (score 6):

You can use Awesome native rules:

```
awful.rules.rules = {
  { rule = { class = "Firefox" },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][1] , switchtotag=true } },
  { rule = { class = "Chromium" },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][2] , switchtotag=true } },
  { rule = { class = "Terminal" },
  properties = { tag = tags[1][3] , switchtotag=true } },
}
```

You can confirm class names with `wmctrl -lx`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Shifty](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Shifty):

> Shifty is an Awesome 3 extension that implements dynamic tagging. It
>   also implements a client matching configuration that simplifies
>   tag-client matching. Here are a few ways of how shifty makes awesome
>   awesomer:
>
> - On-the-fly tag creation and disposal
> - Advanced client matching
> - Easy moving of clients between tags
> - Tag add/rename prompt in taglist completion
> - Reordering tags and configurable positioning
> - Tag name guessing, automagic no-config client grouping
> - Customizable keybindings per client and tag
> - Simple yet powerful configuration

Comment: I don't think Shifty is still a thing

Answer (score 1):

Instructions are located in Awesome FAQ [3.18](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_find_window.27s_class_and_other_identifiers.3F) and [3.19](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#How_to_start_clients_on_specific_tags_and_others_as_floating.3F).